# Click link contained in 3rd <li> tag on load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<ul>`:

```
<ul class="options_inner">
    <li><a data-dk-dropdown-value=".option1"></a></li>
    <li><a data-dk-dropdown-value=".option2"></a></li>
    <li><a data-dk-dropdown-value=".option3"></a></li>
</ul>
```

When the page loads, I'd like to fire a function that clicks the link contained within the 3rd `<li>`. Can this be achieved with JavaScript or jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('ul li:nth-child(3) a').trigger('click');
```

That's it!

Comment: If i want to specify the ul class, would I use:
$('ul.options_inner li:nth-child(3) a').trigger('click');
thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Use [the `nth-child` selector](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/). And put your code in a jQuery `ready` event listener. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.options_inner li:nth-child(3) a').trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the [nth-child selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

```
$('ul li:nth-child(3) a').click() //something like that
```