# On load select 4th option from a select field and click/select

Tags: javascript, jquery

When page loads, click/select the 4th option from a select field

```
<select id="portfolio-filter">
<option value="*">Display by category</option>
<option value=".option1">option1</option>
<option value=".option2">option2</option>
<option value=".option3">option3</option>
<option value=".option4">option4</option>
<option value=".option5">option5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: Please post the code you have written to solve this problem yourself, and the issues you're having with it. At the moment this reads like a specification for a freelancer.

Comment: You've already asked this question today - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391974/click-link-contained-in-3rd-li-tag-on-load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On dom ready:

```
$("#portfolio-filter option:eq(3)").prop("selected", true);
```

`eq` is 0 based, so 4th option = index 3

Answer (score 1):

Or better use "selected" :

```
<option value=".option4" selected>option4</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$('#portfolio-filter option:nth-child(4)').click(); // to click
```

or:

```
$('#portfolio-filter option:nth-child(4)').prop("selected", true); // to select
```